# Login into Oracle Database Error

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, sqlplus

I had installed Oracle 12 to my Linux box. I tried to login using sqlplus but it prompt out this error at below. How to solve it?

> Enter user-name: SYSDBA
>
> Enter password:  ERROR: ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
>
> ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
>
> Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
>
> Additional information: 3701
>
> Additional information: 542678011
>
> Process ID: 0 Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

EDIT: 
How to find out default ORACLE_SID?

Answer (score 2):

There could be various reason for this error.

You are using wrong `ORACLE_SID` and `ORACLE_HOME`.

The instance that you are trying to connect isn't up and running.

***When you have wrong ORACLE SID and HOME.***

I could reproduce the error by changing my SID to something else. My SID is `oracdb`.

```
[oracle@myserver ~]$ ps -ef | grep pmon
oracle   29336     1  0 Apr27 ?        00:00:22 ora_pmon_oracdb
```

But I changed it to `orcl`.

```
[oracle@myserver Desktop]$ export ORACLE_SID=orcl
```

Then I tried to connect to the database using SQL*PLUS.

```
[oracle@myserver Desktop]$ sqlplus sys

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue May 2 00:23:50 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 3701
Additional information: -923528497
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

Then I changed it to original SID.

```
[oracle@myserver ~]$ export ORACLE_SID=oracdb
[oracle@myserver ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue May 2 00:28:40 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
```

***When your instance is down and connected as a non-sys user***

Use the following linux command to check whether some of the important background processes are running or not such PMON or SMON.

```
[oracle@myserver ~]$ ps -ef| grep pmon
oracle   57587 57044  2 00:52 pts/3    00:00:00 grep pmon
```

My oracle instance is down.

Now, as you have tried, I attempt to connect to the database using non-sys user, `sysdba` is a privilege not a database user.

```
[oracle@myserver ~]$ sqlplus sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue May 2 00:53:04 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 3701
Additional information: -688980181
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


Enter user-name:
```

I got the same error as you have got.

Now, connect as `sysdba`/`sysoper` and start the database instance.

```
[oracle@myserver ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue May 2 00:53:36 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
```

Comment: How to find out my default ORACLE_SID?

Comment: You can go to `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs` directory and find initialization parameter files such as `spfile<SID>.ora` or `init<SID>.ora`.

Comment: @peterwkc: Or if your instance is up and running then `$ ps -ef | grep pmon` shows instance name at the end of the process name.

Comment: @peterwkc, For linux  & Solaris , you can also find ORACLE_SID from "pgrep  -lf _pmon_" . And In linux you can also find from this query" select distinct sid from v$mystat;"

Comment: I"m issue this command ps -ef | grep pmon                                                                     root     31688 30893  0 19:19 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto pmon. Is my oracle instance is up? How to start the oracle instance?

Comment: Login as Oracle user. As per the output your are connected as root user. Then follow my answer to start up your database